Create rtsp-server for record and watch stream
I am looking at the example: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-record.c - with launch: decodebin name=depay0 ! autovideosink
When I run:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test

...it works fine and the application displays a window with a test video.
But:
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

...does not work.
It returns an error:

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Additional debug info:
../gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.c(8240): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Server can not provide an SDP.
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Please, tell me, how to change test-record.c for get video from rtsp-server.
with launch: decodebin name=depay0 ! fakesink
and
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location= rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test !  queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink

...the result has not changed
